# CircularQueue in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any type of `Iterable` in Dart whose elements can be rotated to change it's order? Something like Circular Queue?

I tried using `ListQueue` of `dart:collection` but couldn't really figure out how it was supposed to be rotated.

**Example:**

```
print([1,2,3].rotateLeft()); // should print [2,3,1]
```

Any extension method on any specific type will too do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then it is very easy logic you can implement on your own, Look at the following sample

```
void main() {
   List<int> numbers = [1,2,3];
   numbers = shiftingRight(numbers, 1);
   print(numbers);
   numbers = shiftingLeft(numbers, -1);
   print(numbers);

   //Without extra space
   rotateLeft(numbers, 2);
   print(numbers);

}

leftRotatebyOne(List<int> nums) {
  int first = nums[0];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) 
    nums[i] = nums[i+1];

  nums[i] = first;
}


rotateLeft(List<int> nums, int offset) {

  for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
    leftRotatebyOne(nums);
  }
}





List<int> shiftingRight(List<int> nums, int offset) {
    int length = nums.length;
    List<int> temp = List.from(nums);
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      temp[i] = nums[(i + offset) % length];
    }
    return temp;
  }

List<int> shiftingLeft(List<int> nums, int offset) {
  int length = nums.length;
  return shiftingRight(nums, length + offset);
}
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2] //Without extra space
```

Yes you need some verification range of array, but the idea is very simple

Comment: I wanted to internally modify the object instead on instantiating a new one

Comment: The object is assigned new values as you see the example. But for that, I created new space. You can come up with some logic for not using extra space.

Comment: Hmm ... seems like I have to create my own class to implement that logic, thanks for your time though.

Comment: That looks very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing rotation on top of a Queue container, your `rotateLeft()` can be done with `list_queue.addLast(list_queue.removeFirst())`. (And `rotateRight()` would be `list_queue.addFirst(list_queue.removeLast())`.)

Below is an example implementation composed on top of a [ListQueue](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-collection/ListQueue-class.html). (I'm not very experienced with Dart, would be happy to know if the code below isn't ideal. We can't "extend" ListQueue, so I'm wrapping it in a new class and exposing wrapped methods one-by-one.)

```
import 'dart:collection';

class Rotatable<E> {
  ListQueue<E> _queue = ListQueue<E>();

  Rotatable(this._queue);

  factory Rotatable.from(Iterable<dynamic> elements) {
    ListQueue<E> queue = ListQueue.from(elements);
    return Rotatable(queue);
  }

  void addFirst(E value) => _queue.addFirst(value);
  void addLast(E value) => _queue.addLast(value);
  E removeFirst() => _queue.removeFirst();
  E removeLast() => _queue.removeLast();

  void rotateLeft() {
    _queue.addLast(_queue.removeFirst());
  }

  void rotateRight() {
    _queue.addFirst(_queue.removeLast());
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return _queue.toString();
  }
}

void main() {
  var r = Rotatable<int>.from([1, 2, 3]);
  r.addLast(10);
  print(r);
  r.rotateLeft();
  print(r);
}
```

Comment: I haven't yet figured out what the QueueList class in package:collection might be useful for:
https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/QueueList-class.html

(It looks like ListQueue has been around for quite some time - e.g. already in Dart version 2.0.0).